# rails server confused when class name equals module name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, webrick

[preface: This question is mostly idle curiosity -- there are clear workarounds -- but an answer might give me insight into something fundamental I don't understand.]

I've been using a namespaced model where the class name is also the module name, like this:

```
# file: external.rb
module External
  require 'external/external.rb'
  require 'external/other.rb'
end

# file: external/external.rb
module External
  class External < ActiveRecord::Base ; end
end

# file: external/other.rb
module External
  class Other < External ; end
end
```

When I run this in the rails console, there's no problem.  But when I run it under the server, I get the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (superclass must be a Class (Module given)):
```

on the line `class Other < External`. Evidently it's confusing the class name with the module name.  Why is this?  Since the class definition is inside the scope of the External module, shouldn't this be interpreted unambiguously as `class External::Other < External::External`?

#### aside

Of course there are a couple of ways to fix this.  One is to fully qualify the class name, as in:

```
module External
  class Other < External::External ; end
end
```

The more familiar approach, and the way I ended up going, was to simply rename the External class to Base:

```
# file: external.rb
module External
  require 'external/base.rb'
  require 'external/other.rb'
end

# file: external/base.rb
module External
  class Base < ActiveRecord::Base ; end
end

# file: external/other.rb
module External
  class Other < Base ; end
end
```

... but I'm still curious why the server got confused (and the console didn't).

Comment: Not sure if it may be an answer to your question (that's why I include it as a comment), but Rails in development mode will usually try to only load as many classes as it needs, so maybe your External model wasn't loaded when Other is loaded. Try puting ```External::External``` just before ```class Other < External ; end``` to test if it may be that.

Comment: You might be right: I recall that the Rails server in dev mode does some 'clever' things with caching classes, and if it loaded external/other.rb without first loading external/external.rb (despite the pair of `require`s in the parent file), I could see how it might get confused.